# javascript name value not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

so now I have a form with this...

```
<INPUT type="text" name="budget[unbudgeted_balance]" value="">   
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button2" Value="Get Funds Value" onClick="writeText(this.form)">
```

And some coffeescript as such...

```
window.writeText = (form) ->
  form.budget[unbudgeted_balance].value = "frack"
```

translated to JS as such...

```
window.writeText = function(form) {
  return form.budget[unbudgeted_balance].value = "frack";
};
```

If I do name="budget"...It works. BUT if I do name="budget[unbudgeted_balance]", it won't work, why is this. How do I fix?

Comment: Global variables are bad (window...) http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad. CoffeeScript sets out to help solve the accidental use of them. If you're going to speifically ask for something in the global scope you should ensure there are no other alternatives first :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the field is `budget[unbudgeted_balance]`. Try:

```
form.elements["budget[unbudgeted_balance]"].value = "frack"
```

Comment: TrueBlue does justice to the name. That was it!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know coffeescript so this is just a guess

```
window.writeText = (form) ->
  form["budget[unbudgeted_balance]"].value = "frack"
```